# Keras: custom loss function over entire prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm wondering if there is any way in Keras to define a loss function "Loss(Yhat)"

that takes in the predicted data *as a whole* at the end of an epoch. As far as I can see Keras only allows loss to be calculated per batch but I'm wondering if there is a workaround anyone knows of.

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, if possible, make your batch size equal to the entire training data set.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you looking for `print(model.evaluate(x_train, y_train))`?

If you do want to see that "every" epoch, you can add it into a callback, but that would consume too much time:

```
printEvaluation(e,logs):

    print("evaluation for epoch: " + str(e))
    print(model.evaluate(x_train,y_train))

callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end= printEvaluation)
callbacks = [callback]

model.fit(........, callbacks = callbacks)
```